# Inherited control won't refresh after visual properties changed

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have a MLable which inherit Label . It's backcolor is red. I can use it on forms with red background. But when i want to change background to black from MLabel customcontrol, already added labeles doesn't effect. Only new MLabel's background black, others red. What the ???

Should i have to change them one by one?

SAMPLE CODE:

MLabel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestCControl
{
    public partial class CustomControl1 : Label
    {
        public CustomControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
            base.OnPaint(pe);
        }
    }
}
```

Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestCControl
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Form1.Designer.cs

```
namespace TestCControl
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.customControl11 = new TestCControl.CustomControl1();
            this.customControl12 = new TestCControl.CustomControl1();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // customControl11
            // 
            this.customControl11.AutoSize = true;
            this.customControl11.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            this.customControl11.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 23);
            this.customControl11.Name = "customControl11";
            this.customControl11.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(86, 13);
            this.customControl11.TabIndex = 0;
            this.customControl11.Text = "customControl11";
            // 
            // customControl12
            // 
            this.customControl12.AutoSize = true;
            this.customControl12.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Maroon;
            this.customControl12.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(140, 74);
            this.customControl12.Name = "customControl12";
            this.customControl12.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(86, 13);
            this.customControl12.TabIndex = 1;
            this.customControl12.Text = "customControl12";
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
            this.Controls.Add(this.customControl12);
            this.Controls.Add(this.customControl11);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private CustomControl1 customControl11;
        private CustomControl1 customControl12;
    }
}
```

As you can see one of the custom control has black other maroon backcolor. Changes on MLabel doesn't effect previously added controls on winform.

Comment: Please provide some more detail and sample code showing what you have done and are trying to do.

Comment: Create a Custom control and inherit from Label, name it MLabel. Change it's BackColor from Designer to Red. Use it on a WinForm. Than go back to MLabel.cs and Change it's backcolor to Red. Compile. Add to winform. You will see first MLabel background red other is black. Did i know wrong or all the MLabels background must change to black?

Comment: If you want all your labels background colours to change, then they all have to be using the same colour variable, not the same value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things to check here.

Are all of your MLabels referring to the same version?  (probably)

How are you setting background of the MLabel control, is it a change to the default background color?

How are you changing the existing MLabels, are you setting them manually in the code, or are you relying on the default background color?

Also, check your winform code. If the designer code sets the MLabel background color explicitly, then this will override any defaults the control may have. If that is the case, then you will need to either remove the background color setting so that it uses the default, or you will have to change each one manually.

If the above all seems correct, then some code and/or a little more information would be useful here.

Updated Answer after seeing actual code:

In CustomControl1 you will want to do something like this:

```
 System.Drawing.Color _backColor = System.
 protected override System.Drawing.Color BackColor 
 {
     get{return _backColor;} 
     set{_backColor = value;}
 }
```

In the Form1.Designer.cs remove the lines that set the BackColor. These are explicitly setting the backcolor and not allowing a default color

```
this.customControl11.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
```

Comment: They all refering to same version.
Changing BackColor from Visual Studio designer. If i change it from code, all works fine.

When i check the forms.Designer.cs file, previously added MLabels BackColor still stay red. Won't effect after changing to black. Again, i'm changing BackColor from Visual Studio Designer.

Comment: I just added an also to my list of checks, without seeing any code that sounds like it could be your problem. When you change the background color from the designer, then it sets it in the designer code. This explicit set overrides any default color of the control.

Comment: There is no extra code. I'm doing all these stuff from designer. Only i can write may be this: public partial class MLabel: Label

Comment: Yes, but when you change things from the designer, those changes are reflected in generated code. I think some sample code code would be very useful at this point.

Comment: I added sample code. As you can see 

this.customControl11.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

And

this.customControl12.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Maroon;

customControl11 first added with Black background. Than i changed the MLabel's usercontrol backcolor to maroon and added customControl12 . One has black color one had maroon. Changes on MLabel doesn't reflect on winform.

Comment: Aha! I will edit my response to address this now that I see the code.

Comment: Ok, i got it. Removing backcolor property from Form1.designer.cs, makes it maroon. It's a think and good one. But should i have to remove them manually one by one?

Comment: Yes, each item will need to be removed manually. When the code does not explicitly set the BackColor, then the control's default is applied. As soon as it is explicitly set in the code, then it overrides the default all the time.

Comment: And this is the end of my Question, i thing i got the answer. Very helpfull answer, thanks @JustinPihony.